# How to export all the data from Grafana as Excel/PDF

Tags: grafana, grafana-api

I have created a dashboard in grafana with Graphs and Singlestat i would like to export all the data which is shown in the dashboard either as PDF/Excel.
I have tried with the following plugin which takes a snapshot of the dashboard and exports it as a PDF. Similarly is there any way where we can export all the data as Excel?. In Grafana there is an option to export individual panel data as CSV/Excel. But I would like to export the data from all panels

https://github.com/IzakMarais/reporter

I have tried with the CorpGlory for Excel download but it is not supported Grafana V.7+.If anyone tried exporting the data as PDF/Excel using opensource kindly help me.Thanks in advance